# if/else loop wrong implementation

Tags: android

```
 private void calculate()
  {
      x=Double.parseDouble(amount1.getText().toString());
      y=Double.parseDouble(amount2.getText().toString());
      a=Double.parseDouble(amount3.getText().toString());

      z=(a*703)/(((x*12)+y)*((x*12)+y));
      tt.setText(Double.toString(z));

  }
```

**This is what I have, everything is working properly. So, Now what I am trying to implement is, when the value of tt is less than 5, it should give an output of " you loss".
basically want to implement if/else condition. But not able to do it.
I thought of doing this:

```
if( tt.equals(<=5)
{
   tt.setText("you loss");
}
else(tt.equals(>=5 && <10)
{
    tt.setText("you won" );
}
```

Please help, I know the implementing the condition wrong.**

Comment: You mean If/else "structure" ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `tt` is a text box, you need to get the value and convert it to an actual number. Is that what the `z` value is?

Once you have the number:

```
if (z < 5) {
    tt.setText(...);
} else if ((z >= 5) && (z < 10)) {
    tt.setText(...);
}
```

[Here's a brief tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html). I'd strongly recommend spending some time getting to know the most basic syntactic elements of Java before going too much further; it will pay off in the long run. And short.

Comment: i can accept answer in 7 minutes.. so i will wait for 7  minutes.. but thats so stupid of me.. still thanks

Comment: @Gagandeep There's a difference between "not knowing something" and "being stupid" :) There's all sorts of stuff we don't know as developers, it doesn't mean we're dumb :) Well, *I* might be, but I'm an edge case.

Comment: good point, I will keep that in my point. Thanks again for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of If Else statements are as follows in java:

```
if ( condition ) {
    then do this
} else if ( condition 2 ) {
    then do this instead
} else {
    then do this if none of the conditions are satisfied.
}
```

conditions can be == or != or > or < or <= or >=

you can also include double statements which you can learn more about [here](http://codingbat.com/doc/ifboolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check tt value then first can store tt value in a temp variable and then checking it will be easy

```
int temp = Integer.parseInt(tt.getText().toString());

if(tt < 5) 
{
    // whatever u want
}
```